# Reading the fileset from a torrent

Tags: parsing, bittorrent

I want to (quickly) put a program/script together to read the fileset from a .torrent file. I want to then use that set to delete any files from a specific directory that do not belong to the torrent.

Any recommendations on a handy library for reading this index from the .torrent file? Whilst I don't object to it, I don't want to be digging deep into the bittorrent spec and rolling a load of code from scratch for this simple purpose.

I have no preference on language.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Effbot has your question answered](http://effbot.org/zone/bencode.htm). Here is the complete code to read the list of files from .torrent file (Python 2.4+):

```
import re

def tokenize(text, match=re.compile("([idel])|(\d+):|(-?\d+)").match):
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        m = match(text, i)
        s = m.group(m.lastindex)
        i = m.end()
        if m.lastindex == 2:
            yield "s"
            yield text[i:i+int(s)]
            i = i + int(s)
        else:
            yield s

def decode_item(next, token):
    if token == "i":
        # integer: "i" value "e"
        data = int(next())
        if next() != "e":
            raise ValueError
    elif token == "s":
        # string: "s" value (virtual tokens)
        data = next()
    elif token == "l" or token == "d":
        # container: "l" (or "d") values "e"
        data = []
        tok = next()
        while tok != "e":
            data.append(decode_item(next, tok))
            tok = next()
        if token == "d":
            data = dict(zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]))
    else:
        raise ValueError
    return data

def decode(text):
    try:
        src = tokenize(text)
        data = decode_item(src.next, src.next())
        for token in src: # look for more tokens
            raise SyntaxError("trailing junk")
    except (AttributeError, ValueError, StopIteration):
        raise SyntaxError("syntax error")
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = open("test.torrent", "rb").read()
    torrent = decode(data)
    for file in torrent["info"]["files"]:
        print "%r - %d bytes" % ("/".join(file["path"]), file["length"])
```

Answer (score 25):

I would use rasterbar's [libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/) which is a small and fast C++ library.
To iterate over the files you could use the [torrent_info](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#torrent-info) class (begin_files(), end_files()).

There's also a [python interface](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/python_binding.html#using-libtorrent-in-python) for libtorrent:

```
import libtorrent
info = libtorrent.torrent_info('test.torrent')
for f in info.files():
    print "%s - %s" % (f.path, f.size)
```

Comment: This is much simpler code and nice output thanks to this library! For anyone looking for a more human readable list or maybe for a cleaner file list for handling in other scripts, try replacing the torrent file name and trailing slash. For example `print(f.path.replace("test/", ""))`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code from Constantine's answer above, slightly modified to handle Unicode characters in torrent filenames and fileset filenames in torrent info:

```
import re

def tokenize(text, match=re.compile("([idel])|(\d+):|(-?\d+)").match):
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        m = match(text, i)
        s = m.group(m.lastindex)
        i = m.end()
        if m.lastindex == 2:
            yield "s"
            yield text[i:i+int(s)]
            i = i + int(s)
        else:
            yield s

def decode_item(next, token):
    if token == "i":
        # integer: "i" value "e"
        data = int(next())
        if next() != "e":
            raise ValueError
    elif token == "s":
        # string: "s" value (virtual tokens)
        data = next()
    elif token == "l" or token == "d":
        # container: "l" (or "d") values "e"
        data = []
        tok = next()
        while tok != "e":
            data.append(decode_item(next, tok))
            tok = next()
        if token == "d":
            data = dict(zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]))
    else:
        raise ValueError
    return data

def decode(text):
    try:
        src = tokenize(text)
        data = decode_item(src.next, src.next())
        for token in src: # look for more tokens
            raise SyntaxError("trailing junk")
    except (AttributeError, ValueError, StopIteration):
        raise SyntaxError("syntax error")
    return data

n = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = open("C:\\Torrents\\test.torrent", "rb").read()
    torrent = decode(data)
    for file in torrent["info"]["files"]:
        n = n + 1
        filenamepath = file["path"]     
        print str(n) + " -- " + ', '.join(map(str, filenamepath))
        fname = ', '.join(map(str, filenamepath))

        print fname + " -- " + str(file["length"])
```

Answer (score 2):

bencode.py from the original Mainline BitTorrent 5.x client (http://download.bittorrent.com/dl/BitTorrent-5.2.2.tar.gz) would give you pretty much the reference implementation in Python.

It has an import dependency on the BTL package but that's trivially easy to remove. You'd then look at bencode.bdecode(filecontent)['info']['files'].

Comment: this only give the ability to bencode and bdecode strings though, right?
But no knowledge of where the bencoded fileset strings actually start and end. i.e after the bencoded metadata and before the binary block

Comment: The root and info objects are both dictionaries (mappings). There's no inherent ordering of the file metadata and the binary checksum strings, except that by convention dictionaries are output in key name order. You need not concern yourself with storage order, just suck the whole dictionary in.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the ideas above, I did the following:

```
~> cd ~/bin

~/bin> ls torrent*
torrent-parse.py  torrent-parse.sh

~/bin> cat torrent-parse.py
# torrent-parse.py
import sys
import libtorrent

# get the input torrent file
if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    torrent = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Missing param: torrent filename"
    sys.exit()
# get names of files in the torrent file
info = libtorrent.torrent_info(torrent);
for f in info.files():
    print "%s - %s" % (f.path, f.size)

~/bin> cat torrent-parse.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Missing param: torrent filename"
  exit 0
fi

python torrent-parse.py "$*"
```

You'll want to set permissions appropriately to make the shell script executable:

```
~/bin> chmod a+x torrent-parse.sh
```

Hope this helps someone :)